# Check cell value for active conditioning format being applied?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a way to check if a range of cells have a certain conditioning format on them such as cell is highlighted if blah blah blah... ?

Comment: How to you want to check it - manually or programatically?

Comment: programmatically - vba

Comment: If it's related to programming, it should be on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @namish Please note that scripting questions (VBA/cmd/PowerShell/bash ...) are very much on topic on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to examine and run:

```
Sub fourmat()
    Dim r As Range, msg As String

    msg = ""
    For Each r In Selection
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0) & vbTab & r.FormatConditions.Count
    Next r
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

It will list each cell and the number of conditional formats associated with that cell:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

You can test the current state of a cell's format with the [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.15).aspx), but you will need to be able to associate a specific part of the format to a specific condition.

For example, it will tell you if the cell is **Bold**, but you must know what condition made it bold!

Comment: Can I specify the range instead of on the selection of cells?

Comment: @user582635 You can replace `Selection` with any range you like...........or you can re-code to pass the range to the sub..................if you don't want the result in a `MsgBox`, you can pass the string to another sub or return it............??............. **your choice**

Comment: umm. the code shows if the cells have conditioning format, I want to see if the conditioning format is activated. like all the selection cells have conditioning formats but I want to know which cell(s)'s conditioning formatting is active.

Comment: @user582635  Sorry...........I don't know how to do that without evaluating each possible condition for each formatted cell.............sorry.........

Comment: @user582635  See my update to my answer..............it should get you part the way there.

Comment: I only have one formatting which is bold the cell if another has a value I'm looking for. I just want to be able to tell if the conditioning format of that cell is active base on the condition.